# How do I totally disable the auto-disable “feature”?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am a runner, I use Strava. Whatever bag I use to carry my iPhone XR, it may lock and disable itself. I was running in a foreign country today and my family got worried because they were not getting news from me. Even when I reached back, I could not message them because my phone was disabled for 9min. Strava only recorded 10min meaning that my phone was locked for at least 40min. Imy phone seems to have disabled itself after 2km when I did a 20s stop.
How do I totally disable this anti-feature?
I want to be the person who locks and unlocks my phone, with face or code.

Answer (score 3):

The way this is worded is something of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - you can't prevent the auto-disable feature, but what you actually need is the phone to stop 'butt-dialling' by waking in your bag.

Do you have 'raise to wake' switched on? If so, switch it off or make sure the phone goes in your bag upside down. That way, raise to wake is never triggered.

Comment: "Raise to Wake" is in Settings -> Display & Brightness, also in case of keeping it in a bag, consider turning off "Tap to Wake" in Settings -> Accessibility -> Touch.

Comment: @Melonee let me give it a try first! Thanks for the config details.